# Svnsubversion upgrade from 1.6.4 to 1.8.x

Tags: svn

currently i plan to upgrade my **Svnsubversion** which hosted at 32 bits windows 2003 server standard, **SVN** Subversion from 1.6.4 to latest, i had google some article, it look like i have to upgrade from **1.6.4** to **1.7.14** first, then only another upgrade from 1.7.14 to 1.8.5

[1.6 to 1.7.14]

According to the article below i just need to "install the newest libraries and binaries on top of the older ones." ==> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565096/how-to-upgrade-svn-server-from-1-6-to-1-7)

, and for the binary and lib files, i believe i should download from ==> [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/files/1.7.14/apache22/svn-win32-1.7.14.zip)

**am i right ?**

[1.7.14 to 1.8.5]

here is another article mentioned from 1.7 to 1.8 mentioned "you just install the newest libraries and binaries on top of the older ones." ==> 
([Upgrade Subversion Server from 1.7 to 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197676/upgrade-subversion-server-from-1-7-to-1-8))

installer download from  ==> [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/files/1.8.5/apache22/svn-win32-1.8.5.zip)

**Am i right ?**

Can any expert correct me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to upgrade to 1.7.x and then upgrade to 1.8.x.  The [compatibility guarantees](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/community-guide/releasing.html#release-compat) provided by Apache Subversion make it such that there's really no benefit to doing so.

Servers can read and write all versions of the repository back to 1.0.0.

Clients can only read/write the newest working copy format, but the upgrade command should be able to upgrade even 1.0.0 working copies.  However, working copy upgrades don't get as much testing or use since you can simply run a new checkout.  So it's possible you might run into an issue with upgrading a 1.6.4 working copy to 1.8.5.  But I don't think going to 1.7.14 first is going to help much with that anyway.

As far as the "right" location to get binaries or how to install them.  It's difficult to answer that question since there are [many different binaries](https://subversion.apache.org/packages.html) available for Subversion.  I'm not personally familiar with the win32svn packages, but in general it's best to remove the old packages entirely and the install the new ones.  That way you avoid any issues you might have with mixing them.  However, sometimes it's desired to keep both in which case you should follow whatever instructions are available for the packaging you're using.

Comment: thanks @Ben , it make sense from 1.6 to 1.8 directly. about the upgrade package, since i'm using windows, do you think i could just install 2.8 MSI at Svnsuversion will do? or do i need to manually delete those c:\program files\subversion\bin and replace those from 2.8 bin package?

Comment: @XJ - You dont need to delete anything, Just install the 1.8 MSI and that will work it worked for me when i used it on windows.

Comment: @Love In a lot of cases that's true.  But when I'm giving generic advice I'll give the safer advice.  If installing over a previous installation works then that's great.